# Unable to add new node on Redis Cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

This is an existing 5 nodes Redis cluster. Just want to add a new node. All seems to be fine, except that for some reason it's not being added:

```
 root@tssredis07:/home/# ./redis-trib.rb  add-node 172.16.129.112:6379 172.16.128.208:6379
>>> Adding node 172.16.129.112:6379 to cluster 172.16.128.208:6379
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 172.16.128.208:6379)
M: 9205296c296b851a5e3f188f12820c6698cf79f4 172.16.128.208:6379
   slots:6554-9829 (3276 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: e489706f6f963401af755a8310635014793c7376 172.16.128.208:6380
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates f33248f075f4369bb57477f8a0bf6d525346c2fd
S: 3ec915bb4f04cb69badcff1bbe7989ef8e2ae21a 172.16.128.209:6380
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 2bd8f9d88ffd68ddf1bffe0cd4d1f602dfcec10f
S: 63df6426dfe1a94849079eb6c79eea9b87ef5c63 172.16.128.216:6380
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 9205296c296b851a5e3f188f12820c6698cf79f4
M: c820ba6f6736a5407a65eca09de2c19e6b953df6 172.16.128.210:6380
   slots:0-3276 (3277 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
M: 368f4f921b925bc86c428fe42a5ff65619918aa0 172.16.128.216:6379
   slots:3277-6553 (3277 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
M: f33248f075f4369bb57477f8a0bf6d525346c2fd 172.16.128.209:6379
   slots:9830-13106 (3277 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
M: 2bd8f9d88ffd68ddf1bffe0cd4d1f602dfcec10f 172.16.128.210:6379
   slots:13107-16383 (3277 slots) master
   1 additional replica(s)
S: 49f9b6ece401cab1207237c1ea94a8e7ca839236 172.16.128.184:6380
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates 368f4f921b925bc86c428fe42a5ff65619918aa0
S: 35c2d7b46a73b2ad275544caf0485d53a740685f 172.16.128.184:6379
   slots: (0 slots) slave
   replicates c820ba6f6736a5407a65eca09de2c19e6b953df6
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
>>> Send CLUSTER MEET to node 172.16.129.112:6379 to make it join the cluster.
[OK] New node added correctly.
```

But when wanted to see the the cluster nodes from the new node, I don't get them:

```
root@tssredis07:/home/# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster nodes
0e192675e1fb55cca495c9e40c43580b46d344ce :6379@16379 myself,master - 0 0 0   connected
```

Why the new node cluster status is failed?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster info
cluster_state:fail
cluster_slots_assigned:0
cluster_slots_ok:0
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:1
cluster_size:0
cluster_current_epoch:0
cluster_my_epoch:0
cluster_stats_messages_sent:0
cluster_stats_messages_received:0
```

The node was perfect before trying to join the existing cluster, and now:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo bar
(error) CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down
```

The new node configuration file is a copy from another node (and same port) conf file. All is in place. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do "cluster meet"

redis-cli -h 172.16.129.112 cluster meet 172.16.128.208 6379

and check if there is any error